# Is there a word or phrase for a nursing mother not biologically related to the baby she breastfeeds?

Tags: phrases, expressions

Nowadays he have human milk banks.  In the olden days, however, it was not unusual to see a woman nurse the child of another mother who couldn't produce her own milk. Is there a word or phrase for a woman who did it and was not biologically related to the child?

Comment: It wasn't only in "olden days". My friend is a programmer and was born in Silicon Valley. His mother died in childbirth, so he and his twin brother had a wet nurse.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

They're called ***[wet nurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wet_nurse)***. Wikipedia

> - *A wet nurse is a woman who breast feeds and cares for another's child.*  Wet nurses are employed when the mother is unable or chooses not to nurse the child herself.
> - Wet-nursed children may be known as "milk-siblings", and in some cultures the families are linked by a special relationship of milk kinship. Mothers who nurse each other's babies are engaging in a reciprocal act known as cross-nursing or co-nursing.
>
>   - *For years it was a really good job for a woman. In 17th- and 18th-century Britain a woman would earn more money as a wet nurse than her husband could as a laborer. And if you were a royal wet nurse you would be honored for life.*

Comment: Thanks for the addendum. Even after a month, I'm still unsure when and when not to quote the linked source. Hehe, so careless, us noobs.

Comment: you should edit  the part that you think is relevant  to answer the question.

Comment: Okay got it. Will do, moving forward. Tnx

Comment: There are three correct answers but I'll accept this one because it was posted first.

Comment: Thank you @Little Eva. But Josh61 should take more credit. I'm only still learning the ropes. Seems that experience on the site is the best teacher of why answers should follow a certain format.

Comment: Testing @LittleEva --- learned just now, too, that it matters to mind spaces when writing out user handles.

Comment: So, a good answer here, one which will please the cognoscenti, one which elicits positive votes, usually contains a personal or subjective component, linked definitions, usage examples, and supporting data in block quotes, with citations to authority in plain text (somewhere in the answer).

Comment: Re it matters to mind spaces when writing out user handles ... it matters mostly in that it demonstrates thought, care, and attention to detail.

Answer (score 8):

That would be a [*nurse*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nurse) or a [*wet nurse*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wet%20nurse):

> nurse:  1 (a) a woman who suckles an infant not her own :  wet nurse
>
> wet nurse: a woman who cares for and suckles children not her own

Both definitions from Merriam-Webster Online.

Comment: In addition, it was formerly not unusual, I believe, for upper-class women to hire a wet nurse because it was unseemly to be seen nursing - or, one presumes, taking care of one's own children. But I'm not sure where I got this piece of information from.

Comment: In past centuries, the majority of royal babies were handed to a wet nurse soon after their arrival. Royal women were often little more than symbolic figures, delivering child after child to secure a dynasty.http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2013/jul/10/royal-baby-breastfeed-duchess-cambridge

Comment: It is interesting that in the OED there are no examples of the term *breast feeding* until the 20th century. Previously it would have been known as *nursing*. It was only after it became fashionable to bottle-feed children (on cow's milk in some form) that it seems the term *breast feeding* arises.

Comment: @WS2 Or *suckling* referring to the physical action.

Comment: @MattGutting Yes. I should think *suckling* probably disappeared among the genteel middle classes in an earlier wave of what we would call *political correctness*.

Answer (score 5):

Oxford Shorter  (1933 edition)

> Wet nurse, wet-nurse   sb 1620  A woman who is hired to suckle and
>   nurse another woman's child.
>
> Wet-nurse verb transitive,  to serve as a wet nurse.